# In OSB can you change the proxy service or business service WSDL using a Customisation File?

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

In OSB can you change the proxy service or business service WSDL using a Customisation File?

if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I worked it out myself:

```html
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>WSDL</xt:type>
        <xt:path>ProjectName/wsdl/MyWsdlNameOld</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>WSDL</xt:type>
        <xt:path>ProjectName/wsdl/MyWsdlNameNew</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
```

Comment: To create this automatically using the SBConsole, go to: System Administration -> Customization -> Create Customization File        and then select the check-box of the osb project(s) that you want from the list and then click on "Create File", then the browser will prompt you to download the Customization xml file. This will contain the <cus:externalReferenceMap> element and its contents that you need.